# MATLAB: imposing derivatives on spline endpoints

Tags: matlab, spline

I am writing a code in MATLAB to extend the range of available data of lift and drag coefficients of an airfoil (some coefficients depending on the angle of attack of the airfoil) beyond some upper limit `aoa_h` and below some lower limit `aoa_l`.

Specifically I connect some data `[aoa_array Cl_array]` and `[aoa_array Cd_array]` with those C_l and C_d functions:

```
C_l =A_1 sin(2*aoa) + A_2 cos^2(aoa) / sin(aoa)
C_d =B_1 sin^2(aoa)+B_2 cos(aoa)
```

For the data, I use the MATLAB `spline` function to insure smoothness. I also would like to impose the spline derivative at the upper and lower limits of the data to be the same as the function I connect it with. I calculated these 
[derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBUMR.png) :

```
dC_l/dalpha=A_1 2(1-2sin^2(alpha))-A_2 cos(alpha)(1+1/sin^2(alpha))
dC_d/dalpha =B_1 2sin(alpha) cos(alpha)-B_2 sin(alpha)
```

Here is the code I use:

```
    function [Cl,Cd]=LD_simple(aoa,aoa_array,Cl_array,Cd_array)
    % Preallocation
    l=length(aoa);
    Cl=zeros(l,1);
    Cd=zeros(l,1);

    % Highest data of aoa, Cl and Cd
    Cl_high=Cl_array(end);
    Cd_high=Cd_array(end);
    aoa_h=aoa_array(end);
    sinaoa_h=sind(aoa_h);
    cosaoa_h=cosd(aoa_h);

    % Lowest data of aoa, Cl and Cd
    Cl_low=Cl_array(1);
    Cd_low=Cd_array(1);
    aoa_l=aoa_array(1);
    sinaoa_l=sind(aoa_l);
    cosaoa_l=cosd(aoa_l);

    % Coefficients for Viterna and Corrigan approximation
    Cd_max=1.11+3*0.18; % empiric relation
    A1=Cd_max/2;
    B1=Cd_max;

    % Coefficients that are tweaked for the function to match the data at endpoints
    A2_h=(Cl_high-Cd_max*sinaoa_h*cosaoa_h)*sinaoa_h/cosaoa_h^2;
    B2_h=(Cd_high-Cd_max*sinaoa_h^2)/cosaoa_h;

    A2_l=(Cl_low-Cd_max*sinaoa_l*cosaoa_l)*sinaoa_l/cosaoa_l^2;
    B2_l=(Cd_low-Cd_max*sinaoa_l^2)/cosaoa_l;

    % Index for splines and extrapolation
    index1=aoa<=max(aoa_array_t) & aoa>=min(aoa_array_t); % aoa in data range
    index2=aoa>max(aoa_array_t); % aoa higher than data range
    index3=aoa<min(aoa_array_t); % aoa lower than data range

    % Endpoints derivatives
    dCl_h=A1*2*(1-2*sinaoa_h^2)+A2_h*(-cosaoa_h-cosaoa_h/sinaoa_h^2);
    dCl_l=A1*2*(1-2*sinaoa_l^2)+A2_l*(-cosaoa_l-cosaoa_l/sinaoa_l^2);
    dCd_h=2*B1*sinaoa_h*cosaoa_h-B2_h*sinaoa_h;
    dCd_l=2*B1*sinaoa_l*cosaoa_l-B2_l*sinaoa_l;

    % Spline interpolation and Viterna&Corrigan extrapolation
    Cl(index1)=spline(aoa_array,[dCl_l; Cl_array; dCl_h], aoa(index1));
    Cd(index1)=spline(aoa_array,[dCd_l; Cd_array; dCd_h], aoa(index1));
    Cl(index2)=A1*sind(2*aoa(index2))+A2_h*(cosd(aoa(index2))).^2./sind(aoa(index2));
    Cd(index2)=B1*sind(aoa(index2)).^2+B2_h*cosd(aoa(index2));
    Cl(index3)=A1*sind(2*aoa(index3))+A2_l*cosd(aoa(index3)).^2./sind(aoa(index3));
    Cd(index3)=B1*sind(aoa(index3)).^2+B2_l*cosd(aoa(index3));
end
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQKG.png)

Would anyone know what could be the issue ?